# A question on f.g. ideals of $\textrm{Hol}(\mathbb{C}^2,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, several-complex-variables

Suppose that $I$ and $J$ are finitely generated ideals of the ring $\textrm{Hol}(\mathbb{C}^2,\mathbb{C})$ of all entire functions in two complex variables.

Then is $I\cap J$ finitely generated too?